# Dojo date constraint to a single day per month

Tags: javascript, html, dojo, dijit.form

Is it possible to make a constraint to only allow the first day of each much a valid option? I'd like to grey out all other dates but I can't seem to find out how to do this? I'm trying to find something useful in Dojo's so called documentation but no luck so far. I understand sending a date to the min and max but that doesn't really solve my issue.

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dijit/form/DateTextBox.html

This is what I've been playing with:

```js
dojo.require("dijit.form.DateTextBox");
```

```html
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.3/dojo/resources/dojo.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.3/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.3/dojo/dojo.js" djConfig="parseOnLoad:true"></script>

<body class="claro">
  <div name="BeginDate" type="text" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.DateTextBox" constraints="{selector:'date',min:'2012'}" datePattern="dd/MMM/yy" value="@Model.BeginDate">
    <script type="dojo/connect" args="newValue" data-dojo-event="onChange">
    </script>
  </div>
```

Comment: there is an isDisabledDate constraint on the Calendar widget that is itself a function and lets you enable/disable individual dates.  I do not think that is supported on DateTextBox, though.

Comment: You're right on it not currently being supported. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can the user simply select the month and not worry about the day?  If so there is a `dojox.form.MonthTextBox` located in `dojox/form/DateTextBox.js`.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing the magical link to where Dojo has good documentation, but what is provided on the Dojo Toolkit website is far from good in my opinion. Anyways, my best luck has been to look at the tests, but of course these don't work.  http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/form/tests/test_DateTextBox.html Where do you look for good examples/documentation?

Comment: I wrote about the resources that I generally use http://swingingcode.blogspot.com/2012/05/dojo-resources.html

Comment: Since your answer technically solves my problem, I'll give it to ya. However because of my special requirements, the MonthTextBox didn't quite cut it. I ended up changing the value to the 1st of the month on the situations that required it and there is an option to display a message, so I did that with an explanation. Thanks for the help!

Comment: The best documentation seems to be the examples in the 'test' directories... For most of dojox components it's hard to find a working example in Internet :(